# Filtrar dados por período

Tags: sql

Estou com problemas ao montar uma *sql* para meu sistema.

Tenho uma tabela `anuencias` com uma coluna `status`. Quero listar dados onde no *status* contenham palavras "assinatura", "pronta pra envio" e "cartorio" mas que esses dados sejam de um determinado período que o usuário informar.

Tenho uma coluna chamada `created` onde é gravada a data e hora de cada registro que poderia utilizar para fazer o filtro dos dados por período usando a função `between`.

Tentei fazer algo assim, mas a consulta retorna todos os registros.

```
SELECT * FROM anuencias 
WHERE status like '%ASSINATURA%' OR 
   status like '%PRONTA PRA ENVIO%' OR 
   status like '%CARTORIO%' OR 
   created BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31'
```

Comment: coloca o código que você fez e/ou as tabelas que tem pra facilitar pra gente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade você precisa que **obrigatoriamente** a data seja entre as duas definidas; então o *select* ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM anuencias 
WHERE (status like '%ASSINATURA%' OR status like '%PRONTA PRA ENVIO%' OR status like '%CARTORIO%')
   AND created BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31'
```

OBS: na pergunta você diz que quer *"listar dados onde no status contenham palavras 'assinatura', 'pronta pra envio' e 'cartorio'"* , mas seu *select* traz qualquer ocorrência de uma das palavras no `status`. Caso queira que o `status` contenha as três expressões, o *select* correto seria o abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM anuencias 
WHERE status like '%ASSINATURA%' AND
   status like '%PRONTA PRA ENVIO%' AND
   status like '%CARTORIO%' AND 
   created BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31'
```